# Get value from array have a multirows

Tags: php, arrays

I Have this array and i want to get all parent have a balance :

this array is multi rows note that sub-array is not static could be more 
Thanks

```
 $array_content = [
        'id'=> 4,    
        'Parent' => [
            [
                'id'        => 54,
                'Parent'  => [
                    [
                        'id'      => 324,
                        'KUI'    => 'ABC',
                        'figure'  => 'Tira',  
                        'Parent'=> []  
                    ],
                    [
                        'id'        => 52355,
                        'lft'       => 'LEFT',
                        'Parent'  => [
                            [
                                'id'        => 4,
                                'Parent'  => [
                                    [
                                        'id'      => 234,
                                        'ui' => 'UITed',
                                        'Parent'=> ['Balance'=>450.3]  
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                'id'      => 76,
                                'ui' => 'some value',
                                'Parent'=> []  
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
             ],
             [
                'id'        => 23,
                'title'     => 'ABC',    
                'Parent'  => [

                ],
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

The output that i need to see is this balance by the id =234 from parent:

```
'Balance'=>450.3
```

Comment: And you have tried with what?

Comment: seems like another case for  `RecursiveIteratorIterator` + `RecursiveArrayIterator` combo

Comment: im still dont figure how to do that

Comment: You have to use recursive function for your array.

Comment: You will have only one "balance" value? Or you can have multiple "balance" for multiple parent?

Comment: multi with a spécific  id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here i found the answer Thanks everyone :

```
  $array_content = [
        'id'=> 4,    
        'Parent' => [
            [
                'id'        => 54,
                'Parent'  => [
                    [
                        'id'      => 324,
                        'KUI'    => 'ABC',
                        'figure'  => 'Tira',  
                        'Parent'=> []  
                    ],
                    [
                        'id'        => 52355,
                        'lft'       => 'LEFT',
                        'Parent'  => [
                            [
                                'id'        => 4,
                                'Parent'  => [
                                    [
                                        'id'      => 234,
                                        'ui' => 'UITed',
                                        'Parent'=> ['Balance'=>450.3]  
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                'id'      => 76,
                                'ui' => 'some value',
                                'Parent'=> []  
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
             ],
             [
                'id'        => 23,
                'title'     => 'ABC',    
                'Parent'  => [

                ],
            ]
        ]
    ];


    function search($arr,$id)
    {
        if(gettype($arr) == 'array')
        foreach($arr as $key =>$list)
    {

        if(gettype($list) == 'array'){  
        if(isset($list['id']))
        {
            if($list['id'] ==$id)
            print_r($list['Parent']);


        }
            search($list,$id);
        }
    }

    }

    foreach($array_content as $key)
    {

        search($key,234);


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also, instead of iterating the array, make it Json and use substr and strpos (or regex) to find the value.

```
$json = json_encode($array_content);
$pos = strpos($json, "Balance\":")+9; // +9 for Balance": is 9 characters
Echo substr($json, $pos, strpos($json, "}", $pos)-$pos); // 450.3
```

https://3v4l.org/cojXe

Comment: i need the balance in the parent  for id =234